# power BI user relationship join as a calculated column Not Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables

```
 Primary Diag
L021
L022
L023
L024
L025
L026
```

and Look_Up_New

```
ICD ICD2    Inclusion Type
L021    L021    3
L022    L022    2
L023    L023    2
L024    L024    4
L025    L025    5
L026    L026    4
L027    L029    5
```

there are two relationship one active and the other not
[image]

The active one is `ICD`
when I wrote the below dax for the active one it works fine

```
Diag 1 = IF(diag[Primary Diag]=BLANK(),"X",
            IF(RELATED(Look_Up_New[ICD]) = BLANK(),"X",
              RELATED(Look_Up_New[Inclusion Type])))
```

but when i wrote for the inactive one i got an error

```
Diag 2 = CALCULATE(IF(diag[Sec. Diag 2]=BLANK(),"X",
            IF(RELATED(Look_Up_New[ICD2]) = BLANK(),"X",
              RELATED(Look_Up_New[Inclusion Type]))),
              USERELATIONSHIP(Look_Up_New[ICD2],Diag[Primary Diag]))
```

[image]

How can I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails is that CALCULATE forces a [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) (i.e. it transforms [row context into filter context](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/row-context-and-filter-context-in-dax/)), which means RELATED no longer has the row context it needs to operate.

Note this remark from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax):

> The RELATED function needs a row context; therefore, it can only be used in calculated column expression, where the current row context is unambiguous, or as a nested function in an expression that uses a table scanning function. A table scanning function, such as SUMX, gets the value of the current row value and then scans another table for instances of that value.

I'd suggest a slightly different approach:

```
Diag 1 = 
CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Look_Up_New[Inclusion Type], "X" ) )

Diag 2 = 
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Look_Up_New[Inclusion Type], "X" ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Diag[Primary Diag], Look_Up_New[ICD2] )
)
```